# How do I align this ionic + angular ion-input div css

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a list of products with buttons to increase and decrease quantity, until this point it is working, however I would like that the user could click on the quantity and enter a specific value instead of just using the buttons of increase and decrease quantity, its working too no problem at this point.
For this I changed the div to an ion-input using the same CSS, the problem is in the alignment of the text within the quantity ion-input.
I can change the code for any other object as long as it works.

[printscreen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHUy0.jpg)

my html:

```
<ion-header>
```

Financeiro Itens

```
<div class="left_div" *ngFor="let item of this.srv_Finan.dis_Itens | sortBy:'desc':'Data'">

  <div class="second_div">
    <ion-label class="prize">{{item.Nome}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label class="name">Preço: {{srv_Util.convertCurrency(item.Preco)}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label class="name">Qtde. Dev.: {{item.QtdeD}}</ion-label>
  </div>


  <div class="last_div">

    <ion-button (click)="plus(item)" size="small" fill="clear" [hidden]="this.srv_Finan.roAddI">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>

    <div class="text_div">
      <!-- TODO: Esse é o original alinhado, mas não editavel -->
      <div class="lbl_div">{{item.Qtde}}</div>
      <!-- <div class="lbl_div">
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="item.Qtde" type="number" pattern="\d*" (click)="selectAll($event)"></ion-input>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <ion-button (click)="minus(item)" size="small" fill="clear" [hidden]="this.srv_Finan.roAddI">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="remove-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_content_div{
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;

.left_div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .back_image{
        height: 110px;
        width: 110px;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 5px;
        min-width: 110px;
    }

    .second_div{
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        .prize{
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-top: 10px;

        }
        .name{
            color: gray;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    }

    .last_div
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        ion-button{
            margin: 0;
            color: gray;
        }

        .text_div
        {
            text-align: center;

            .lbl_div
            {
                background: #1F1A3C;
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                margin: auto;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                color: white;
                font-weight: 600;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Share you complete html with other parts so people can understand better.

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush, but I did share the full code and create a better explanation of  the problem.